# Как отслеживать наличие работающего приложения в Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

У меня есть приложение мастер, которое запускает несколько дочерних приложений (копий самого себя, но с другим ключом в коммандной строке). Во время работы, дочерние приложения выполняют некую работу и мастер-приложение собирает и аггрегирует их результаты. Если приложение мастер закрывается штатно, то оно останавливает все дочерние приложения. Но, иногда, мастер закрывается нештатно (например, падает, или убивается из диспетчера задач). В таком случае, все дочерние приложения продолжают работать .. приходится их завершать вручную.

Варианты, что приходят на ум:

- регулярно передавать из мастера сообщения дочерним приложениям. Если сообщение не пришло - мастера нет и надо закрываться. Такой вариант не подходит, т.к. мастер может подвиснуть на время обработки данных или быть приостановлен в отладчике.
- создавать из мастера мютекс с меткой времени. Дочерними проверять, если свежего мютекса нет - мастера нет и надо закрываться. Но не будет ли расточительным, создавать по мютексу раз в 5сек на протяжении часа, например?
- передавать в дочерние приложения некий идентификатор процесса мастера и проверять его наличие? Не имя, т.к. оно у всех общее, а что-то еще? Как это сделать?
- как-то еще?

Какой способ правильнее и оптимальнее?
Как можно из дочерних приложений отслеживать, что приложение-мастер закрылось?

Comment: Достаточно создать один именованный мютекс в родителе, захватить его, а в дочерних открыть мютекс и повесить `WaitForSingleObject` на ожидание. Как только родитель закроется и освободит мютекс, дочерние тут же получат сигнал об этом и закроются по очереди.

Comment: @zed Система гарантирует убитие мютекса на завершении процесса?

Comment: Да, если мютекс не закрыть руками, то система это отследит и пришлёт результат `WAIT_ABANDONED` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, благодаря помощи zed, получилось сделать.

В мастере пишем:

```
// GUID сгенерирован случайным образом (Ctrl+Shift+G)
CreateMutex(nil, True, PChar('{D7576A9B-F93C-4F81-9555-6AD8D34E8972}'));
```

В дочерних добавляем:

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  var
    h: Cardinal;
  begin
    h := OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, False, PChar('{D7576A9B-F93C-4F81-9555-6AD8D34E8972}'));
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    Halt;
  end).Start;
```

Теперь при закрытии мастера, по любой причине, дочерние приложения тоже само-закрываются. Да, `Halt` это очень грубое закрытие, но для прототипа - сойдет.

Comment: А если просто дочерний процесс завершается - он же не сможет остановить анонимный поток (поскольку ничего не знает про него) и останется висеть в процессах... Но для прототипа, возможно, и не важно.

Comment: @kami разве операционка его не прибьет?

Comment: через Halt - прибьет, конечно. А при штатном завершении - нет :)

Comment: @kami интересный расклад, от чего так?

Comment: сделал тестовое приложение. Нет, я был не прав. По крайней мере - для 10.2 (но думаю и раньше было то же самое). Штатное завершение основного потока вызывает ExitProcess, что (как пишет MSDN) - завершает напрочь все потоки кроме текущего без объявления войны. Так что - использование анонимки в данном случае грозит только утечками, которые в свете завершения процесса не являются сколь-либо значимыми